# How to disable the expansion icon if number of lines is within limits? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, expandable

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwYfQ.png)

I want to disable the expandable icon if the number of lines is within the threshold limit.
I am using the `ExpandablePanel` widget, but I am not able to figure out how to disable the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the number of lines using

```
final span = TextSpan(text: txt);
final tp = TextPainter(
text: span, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, maxLines: 3);
tp.layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);
```

then I used `hasIcon: tp.didExceedMaxLines ? true : false,` to enable/disable the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional operator in **hasIcon** to disable the icon

First get the number of lines your text takes up and then use a conditional operator to make the icon visible/invisible

```
final numLines = '\n'.allMatches(yourText).length + 1;


ExpandablePanel(
  .
  .
  .
  hasIcon: numLines > MAX_LINES? true: false,
)
```

Here **MAX_LINES** is the maximum number of lines you have set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then. This was the only way I knew.